# How to access LAN devices and files from iPad, iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, applications, software-recommendation

Are there any **free iOS applications** that let us browse LAN devices, so we could access files from devices in same network.

I use ES File Explorer to do the same in Android phone but I didn't find any free application on iOS. Most of the file explorer for android mobiles include this functionality.

Any such **free app**?

[image]

Comment: There are tons of such apps in the App Store. Maybe you can add some details about specific functionality/protocols you are looking for or list the apps you've tried but didn't like?

Comment: I tried few of the applications like File Explorer, but it required paid/ full version to access those functionality. As I mentioned I only want to access shared files from the devices on same network (LAN)

Answer (score 0):

ES File Explorer is now available for free on iOS and it support LAN Wifi transfers:

[image]

I was able to upload from an Android phone (Chrome) to iOS (ES File Explorer).

Answer (score -2):

iFileExplorer may be what you need. It is free on App store. I am using it.

Comment: Could you expand your answer, preferably with a citation?

Comment: here is the link https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ifileexplorer/id355253462?mt=8